# Change in Date Picker According To Localization

Tags: android, localization, datepicker

I have used Localization in my application for locale and language setting. But the problem is it changes the "date Picker" too according to the locale. I do not want this to happen.
I have to parse this date for later purpose. So i want the date picker to remain same in all locale.

Let me know if any one has the solution.

thanks
Sneha

Comment: Even there you need some localization. because every different place has different time. so whtas the need to keep it constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the [`DatePicker`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html)? If yes, then the format it uses shouldn't matter to you, as the `getYear()`, `getMonth()` and `getDayOfMonth()` methods will work the same, no matter the format.

Comment: yeah.. I have used "DatePicker". But problem is that I am storing picked date like "Tue 13 Sep 2011" in a string format in SQLite once i pick it form DatePicker dialog. So while parsing I get error